# Binary Search using a for loop, searching for words in a list and comparing

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary-search

I'm trying to compare the words in "alice_list" to "dictionary_list", and if a word isnt found in the "dictionary_list" to print it and say it is probably misspelled. I'm having issues where its not printing anything if its not found, maybe you guys could help me out. I have the "alice_list" being appended to uppercase, as the "dictionary_list" is all in capitals. Any help with why its not working would be appreciated as I'm about to pull my hair out over it!

```
       import re
    # This function takes in a line of text and returns
    # a list of words in the line.

    def split_line(line):
        return re.findall('[A-Za-z]+(?:\'[A-Za-z]+)?', line)
    # --- Read in a file from disk and put it in an array.

    dictionary_list = []
    alice_list = []
    misspelled_words = []

    for line in open("dictionary.txt"):
        line = line.strip()
        dictionary_list.extend(split_line(line))

    for line in open("AliceInWonderLand200.txt"):
        line = line.strip()
        alice_list.extend(split_line(line.upper()))


    def searching(word, wordList):
        first = 0
        last = len(wordList) - 1
        found = False
        while first <= last and not found:
            middle = (first + last)//2
            if wordList[middle] == word:
                found = True
            else:
                if word < wordList[middle]:
                    last = middle - 1
                else:
                    first = middle + 1
        return found


    for word in alice_list:
        searching(word, dictionary_list)
```

--------- EDITED CODE THAT WORKED ----------
Updated a few things if anyone has the same issue, and used "for word not in" to double check what was being outputted in the search.

```
"""-----Binary Search-----"""
# search for word, if the word is searched higher than list length, print
words = alice_list
for word in alice_list:
        first = 0
        last = len(dictionary_list) - 1
        found = False
        while first <= last and not found:
            middle = (first + last) // 2
            if dictionary_list[middle] == word:
                found = True
            else:
                if word < dictionary_list[middle]:
                    last = middle - 1
                else:
                    first = middle + 1
                if word > dictionary_list[last]:
                    print("NEW:", word)

# checking to make sure words match
for word in alice_list:
    if word not in dictionary_list:
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `split_line()` returns a list. You then take the output of the function and append it to the dictionary list, which means each entry in the dictionary is a *list* of words rather than a single word. The quick fix it to use `extend` instead of `append`.

```
    dictionary_list.extend(split_line(line))
```

A set might be a better choice than a list here, then you wouldn't need the binary search.

**--EDIT--**
To print words not in the list, just filter the list based on whether your function returns `False`. Something like:

```
notfound = [word for word in alice_list if not searching(word, dictionary_list)]
```

Comment: thank you! I updated my code, can you take a look and see how I can print out what is not in the list?

Comment: @RocktheFries see the small edit above. You should be able build a list of words where `searching()` returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to use binary search for this program? Python has this handy operator called "in". Given an element as the first operand and and a list/set/dictionary/tuple as the second, it returns True if that element is in the structure, and false if it is not.

Examples:

```
1 in [1, 2, 3, 4] -> True
"APPLE" in ["HELLO", "WORLD"] -> False
```

So, for your case, most of the script can be simplified to:

```
for word in alice_list:
    if word not in dictionary_list:
        print(word)
```

This will print each word that is not in the dictionary list.

Comment: I am required to use binary for this to show my knowledge of it, but im stuck on how to print what it DOESNT find, rather than if it does

Comment: If dictionary is sorted, binary search is much faster than `in`, which assumes no ordering and examines up to every element.

Comment: @ggorlen would you know how to return a name that wasnt found in my search?

Comment: I don't understand--if you binary search for something and nothing comes up, you know you didn't find it and can return it. Or you can return the nearest item to the location the item should have been in.